# DateTime conditional expression - VBA

Tags: vba, datetime

I have the following code for executing a macro on opening a workbook, until the time to executing it comes (until a maximum time limit):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim time_executing_macro As Date
Dim maximum_time_to_launch_macro As Date

time_executing_macro = "17:00:00"
maximum_time_to_launch_macro = "19:00:00"

Do
If (Now() >= time_executing_macro) Then
    MsgBox ("OK")
    Exit Sub
End If
Loop Until (Now() >= maximum_time_to_launch_macro)

End Sub
```

The problem is that, as of today at 12:21, the code keeps launching the MsgBox. As far as I know `12:21:00 < 17:00:00`, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Time` instead `Now`. Btw, for `12:21` it will just create infinity loop and freeze your excel. You could use `Application.OnTime` to call macro in certain time

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. It works (in the sense that it freezes, as you said ;) ).